# Cannot create an apk file creation with Buildozer 1.5.1.dev0 ((Ubuntu 23.04 and VirtualBox (MacOS))

Tags: python, android, ubuntu, virtualbox, buildozer

I am trying to create an Apk file with Buildozer 1.5.1.dev0 under Ubuntu 23.04 (with VirtualBox on MacOS 10.14.4.

My application folder contains all the right files

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/the_app$ ls

    __pycache__     design.kv     kivy-buildozer-installer.sh  main.py
    bin             get-pip.py    logout_hover.png             quotes
    buildozer.spec  hoverable.py  logout_nothover.png          users.json
```

The app runs well

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/the_app$ python3 main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/ubuntu/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-08-24_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.4 (main, Jun  9 2023, 07:59:55) [GCC 12.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Mesa'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG  ] STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
[DEBUG  ] STREAM b'IDAT' 41 1216
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: xclip
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

When I run the command line "buildozer android", I get the below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/the_app$ buildozer android

# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Missing target command
Usage:
    buildozer [--profile <name>] [--verbose] [target] <command>...
    buildozer --version

Available targets:
  ios                iOS target, based on kivy-ios project
  android            Android target, based on python-for-android project

Global commands (without target):
  appclean           Clean the .buildozer folder in the app directory.
  distclean          Clean the whole Buildozer environment.
  help               Show the Buildozer help.
  init               Create a initial buildozer.spec in the current directory
  serve              Serve the bin directory via SimpleHTTPServer
  setdefault         Set the default command to run when no arguments are given
  version            Show the Buildozer version

Target commands:
  clean      Clean the target environment
  update     Update the target dependencies
  debug      Build the application in debug mode
  release    Build the application in release mode
  deploy     Deploy the application on the device
  run        Run the application on the device
  serve      Serve the bin directory via SimpleHTTPServer

Target "ios" commands:
  list_identities    List the available identities to use for signing.
  xcode              Open the xcode project.

Target "android" commands:
  adb                Run adb from the Android SDK. Args must come after --, or
                     use --alias to make an alias
  clean              Clean the build and distribution
  logcat             Show the log from the device
  p4a                Run p4a commands. Args must come after --, or use --alias
                     to make an alias
```

When I run the command line "buildozer android debug", I get the  below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/the_app$ buildozer android debug


# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
# Cython (cython) not found, please install it.
```

I am stuck and don't know what to do here to proceed. Whether I use the command line "buildozer android" or "buildozer android debug", it doesn't work and give me the error messages above... Cython is supposed to be installed with Python, which I obviously installed also.

Kindly help

Thx

Comment: Anyone, any idea ??? Been looking at previous threads but couldn't solve the issue with them